# Device Back button control in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, back-button

I am developing a flutter app that has a customer listing and a "Add" Floating button. When i click on Add button , I am taking it to a new screen for adding new customer. In this screen, when device back button is pressed, It should go back to the listing screen. But, instead it is going back to Dashboard.(App Flow : *Dashboard screen(Customers) -> Customer Listing screen -> Add customer Screen*.
I have already tried the Willscope method :

My Add Customer Screen:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

Future<bool> _onBackPressed() async {
  return (await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
      content: new Text('Do you want to exit Add Customer'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
          child: new Text('No'),
        ),
        new FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
          child: new Text('Yes'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )) ?? false;
}

return new
 WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: _onBackPressed,
child : new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(
    title: new Text(widget.title),
    backgroundColor: theme_color,
  ),
  body: new SafeArea(
      top: false,
      bottom: false,
      child: new Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidate: true,
          child: new ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              //Form Elements


              new Container(
                  height: 70,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 20.0),
                  child: new RaisedButton(
                    color: theme_color,
                    child: const Text(
                      'Save',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                    //Send Data to Database
                      }
                    },
                  )), //Save button
            ],
          ))),
));
}
```

Comment: This goes to the dashboard means there is no listing page in your navigator stack

Comment: Remove the method from your build method.

Comment: @SWAGAssassinYT  I have used Navigator.push() to navigate from Dashboard to Cutomer listing and also from Customer listing to Add customer. To check the stack, i added a button in Add customer screen, and called Navigator.pop() in onPressed . The screen moved to the listing. So, i guess, listing is there in the stack

Answer (score 0):

Use this , Instead of return anything .

```
  Future<void> _onBackPressed() async {
      return (await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => new AlertDialog(
          title: new Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: new Text('Do you want to exit Add Customer'),
          actions: <Widget>[
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
              child: new Text('No'),
            ),
            new FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
              child: new Text('Yes'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ));
    }
```